# Message in another form

Tags: cipher

The goal is simple, figure out the message hidden in the numbers!

```
173 207 18  181
179 200 52  175
42  4   61  197
77  92  148 193
145 40  32  181
18  128 199 173
146 128 179 57
88  193 64  204
15  89  23  181
92  74  77  179
168 106 34  197
17  48  196 173
143 40  32  181
```

**Hint 1**

> 211

**Hint 2**

> Based

I am unsure if the tag is correct, but good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Did you create this puzzle yourself?

Comment: Yes, I did make this myself! I've been experimenting with things related to it and decided to post it here to see how cryptic it is! I'll take the tour now, thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, and would like to offer a tip for making your puzzle more appealing to solvers. You may want to read [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) for some guidance on how to turn a cipher challenge into a more interesting puzzle.

Comment: Yeah I see now that this isn't very er, fun to solve. Should I maybe repost after making it a bit nicer?

Comment: @ArchivedButter rather than deleting and reposting, you can edit it. also btw, when replying to people you have to tag them with the @ symbol and then their username. Welcome to Puzzling SE

Comment: @Ankit Alright, thank you! I'm not quite sure how to improve this though..

Comment: @ArchivedButter np. Honestly I think it is fine and doesn't require changes.

Comment: @Ankit Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the challenge, here is the answer:

> speedy brown vulpine leaped over the indolent canine

Explanation (thanks to the tips)

> Data are given 4 by 4, and we have the tip that something is 211 based.
>  (Actually all data are < 211 which matches base 211)
>  After some tries in excel to find correct ordering, let's decode the first line:
>  173+211*(207+211*(18+211*181)) = 0x65657073
>  Cool, all bytes are in ASCII range: 'e', 'e', 'p', 's'.
>  When read in reverse order, we have the beginning of 'speed'.
>  Let's redo for all lines and we have the decode message!

Comment: Ayy! You did it! Good job! The whole reverse order part is specifically because of the bytes being arranged in little-endian format. I'm happy someone solved it! :D